# How to flush the print buffer in R?

Tags: r

I want to run a long-running simulation and have updates printed periodically. However, I am finding that my `print` statements are being buffered, even when I explicitly try to `flush`. Here, for example:

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
    print(i)
    flush(stdout())
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

I would expect this to increment every 1sec, but it outputs everything at the end, after 10 seconds.

How would you force a flush of the print buffer?

Comment: try using `cat(stdout(),sep='\n')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    message(i,"\r",appendLF=FALSE)
    flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `flush.console()` was the key here!

Comment: why sys.sleep() is used here?

Comment: sys.sleep() is used here because otherwise, you couldn't see if the buffer gets flushed after each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cat()`:

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  # Sleep for 1 second
  Sys.sleep(1)

  # Print the current iteration
  cat(paste0("\r", i))      
}
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work.  If the function doesn't have any 'pause' time, the output won't always show up.